# Counting working hours between dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mantis

I am trying to create SQL query that calculates the number of hours between two dates (2015-01-01 12:12:12). The complexity of this query is on sum up hours only between Monday to Friday from 8am to 6pm.

I need it to calculate how long it took for a issue logged in our Mantis BT system to be resolved. Our clients can log issues outside our working hours, but I only want to calculate hours based on our working hours.

We calculate the difference between the date/time when the issue was logged (submitted_date) to when the issue was resolved (maximum updated_date and "resolved" status).  The difficulty is that an issue can be resolved, and then reopened in the future. By using the maximum updated_date, my script is including the days that the issue was in "resolved" status, which is not correct. It should only include days while issue is open.

```
SELECT
    proj.name,
    bugs.id,
    summary,
    users2.username AS Assigned_to,
    CASE bugs.status
        WHEN  '80' THEN  'Resolved'
        WHEN  '90' THEN  'Closed'
    END AS Status,
    bugs.date_submitted AS date_submitted,
    MAX(date_modified) AS last_date_modified
FROM
    mantis_bug_table bugs
    LEFT JOIN mantis_bugnote_table notes ON notes.bug_id = bugs.id
    INNER JOIN mantis_bug_history_table hist ON bugs.id = hist.bug_id
    LEFT JOIN mantis_user_table users2 ON users2.id = bugs.handler_id
    INNER JOIN mantis_project_table proj ON proj.id = bugs.project_id 
WHERE
    bugs.project_id = 102 
    AND hist.field_name = 'status' 
    AND bugs.status IN (80,90) 
    AND date_modified >= '2015-01-01'
GROUP BY
    summary;
```

Comment: Will you have to take into account public holidays or anything that is *specific* to your organisation? If the answer to either is yes, the best first step may be to create and populate a calendar table.

Comment: Yes, I will have to take in consideration public holidays and working hours (8am to 6pm).

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/708719/How-to-Count-Work-Days-Between-Dates-in-SQL-Serv) is written for SQL, but can be replicated easily in MySQL.

You just need to define your working hours, then reference these to calculate the time.